# how to put a foreach in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to put foreach in jquery but I don't know how, can someone help me ?

```
$('#chart').radarChart({
    size: [500, 400],
    step: 1,
    title: " ",
    values: {
    <?php $nim = $this->uri->segment(3); 
          $namapelajaran = $this->modelpenilaian->getchart($nim);
        foreach($namapelajaran as $np){ ///this foreach
    ?>
      "<?php echo $np->name ?>": 5, ///show the name
      "Node.js": 3.5, ///so the result like this
      "jQuery": 4,
      "PHP": 3,
      "C++": 2.5,
      "Problem Solving": 3.5,
      "DHTML": 4 <?php } ?>
    },
    showAxisLabels: true
  });
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean "put a foreach"? Where? To do what? etc.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach, depending on what the type of the collection is. If you need more detailed information than that, please edit your question so the problem is clearer.

Comment: I would recommend to avoid mixing js and php like this. First perform your foreach loop, store the data that you want in a variable and then echo that variable in your js code.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your js separate from php code. Mixing them gets ugly and makes debugging more complicated

Pass your data to a javascript variable in a `<script>` tag as json.

```
<script>
   var chartVals = <?php echo json_encode($data)?>;
</script>
```

Then use that variable in your chart config.

```
$('#chart').radarChart({
    size: [500, 400],
    step: 1,
    title: " ",
    values: chartVals ,
    showAxisLabels: true
});
```